# GORM 'NOT IN' subquery

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to execute a subquery like:

```
 SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE col1='val1' and col2 NOT IN (
  SELECT ID FROM table2 WHERE col1='val1' and col3 = 'val3')
```

How can I use [GORM](http://gorm.io/) to execute it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GORM](http://gorm.io/) can [compose](http://gorm.io/docs/query.html#SubQuery) queries.

Write a standard query and then call the `.SubQuery()` method:

```
sub := db.Table("table2").Select("ID").Where("col1 = ?", 'val1').SubQuery()
```

The you can place it as a parameter in the `.Where()` method

```
err := db.Table("table1").Where("col2 NOT IN ?", sub).Find(&table1Type).Error
//handle the error
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't find a SubQuery() method on the db connection object. I use this with go.